# how to retrieve data using spring mvc and angular js

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

controller code

```
@RequestMapping(value="/welcomes", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces="MediaType.application/json")
    public @ResponseBody ModelAndView welcome(@ModelAttribute UserBean userBean)
    {
        List<UserBean> usernames=new ArrayList<UserBean>();
        usernames = retrievedataservice.findAllUsers(userBean);
        System.out.println(usernames.size());
        return new ModelAndView("welcomes", "usernames", usernames);
    }
```

angular js code

```
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('UserController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
        $scope.reload = function () {
            $http({
                method : 'GET',
                url : 'welcomes'
            }).then(function successCallback(response){
                 $scope.usernames=response.data.usernames;
                 console.log("Success");
                 console.log($scope.usernames);
             },function errorCallback(response) {
                 $scope.err_state = true;
                 console.log(response.statusText);
             });
        };
             $scope.reload();

    }]);
    </script>
<div data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="UserController">
   <table border="1" width="50%" height="50%"> 
    <tr><th>user name</th><th>phone</th><th>email</th></tr>
     <tr data-ng-repeat="user in usernames">
     <td>{{user.username}}</td>
      <td>{{user.phone}}</td>
       <td>{{user.email}}</td>
       </tr>   
   </table>
```

Actually, the controller returns the list of data, but angular js cannot get the data. console.log($scope.usernames); return the null values. it cannot integrate with angular js and controller.

Comment: I think you inserting the wrong URL for GET request

Comment: Sir,  I gave full URL of http://localhost:8080/SpringAngular/welcomes.I change welcomes of url how to give URL

Comment: as that an GET request, did you try it on your browser? It works? Are you sure the problem is in angularjs?
try to copy your URL and past in your browser

Comment: yeah browser console display the output "success" but it didn't return any data